# parse a password protected json url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json url that can be accessed after authentication of username and password.How to put authentication dynamically while parsing the url?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP Basic Auth or some custom login system?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have session based authentication. Then do not put JSON file into location where your public static content is stored. Instead put it somewhere else and create a script in the language you use on the server side that will either deliver file if the user is authenticated or return forbidden HTTP status 403 otherwise.